# F# code porting from windows to ubuntu

Tags: f#, ubuntu-16.04

I am windows developer and trying to write a program on ubuntu in F#
I have ubuntu 16.04 and I am following video https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/T661

I have installed dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2.1-003177
Now I am able to do a small hello world program in C#
But when I follow steps from above video I get error when I do 'dotnet run'
"
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.1.0
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0'.
"
Also one thing I observed is I don't have 'Nuget.config' like the video shows.

I have below questions:

1. How to resolve above query
2. Is there any tutorial available for development of f# on ubuntu either using .net core or mono as finally I would like to port my Actor model akka.net code from windows to ubuntu.

Regards,

Amit Bhagwat

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio, F# are you using? .NET Core support was added in F# 4.1, which is supported in VS 2017 RC.

Comment: I am using visual studio code, but on ubuntu I am giving below commands as suggested in video dotnet --lang f#  dotnet restore and then dotnet run when I try to compile/run by giving last command on linux it gives me the above mentioned error.

Comment: If your project is using project.json, look for "Microsoft.NETCore.App" in there and beneath that the line "version": "1.0.0".  Change it to "version": "1.1.0".

Comment: @user2281729 did you solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry guys for too much delayed reply as I got shifted to another task, I used visual studio 15 and used 64 bit compiler option(off course my code was earlier worked on MONO unix) used this exe on Ubuntu and it worked absolutely fine. I didn't use dot net core as many f# libraries are not supported yet, e.g type providers, akka.net(facing compiler issues in dot net itself)